# T-SQL Sort nvarchar that consists of comma

Tags: sql-server

Given

```
DECLARE @InvoiceNo nvarchar(MAX)

SET @InvoiceNo='10,1,2,3,4,5'

SELECT @InvoiceNo
--10,1,2,3,4,5
```

How to sort it ascendingly to get

```
--1,2,3,4,5,10
```

Comment: If at all possible, change your design so that you store multiple values in a type *designed* for holding multiple values, such as separate rows in a table, or JSON or XML. The start and end of problems you'll have here will always be the decision to cram these multiple values into a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2017 or later, we can use a combination of `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG` here:

```sql
DECLARE @InvoiceNo nvarchar(MAX)
SET @InvoiceNo='10,1,2,3,4,5'

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT value
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@InvoiceNo, ',')
)

SELECT STRING_AGG(value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CAST(value AS int)) AS InvoiceNo
FROM cte;
```